# VBOX Guest Additions Won't Install on Centos 6.5 after updates

Tags: linux, centos, virtualbox

I have a Vbox server running Centos 6.5 32bit, and I have it set as a dev server for some web apps I'm working on.

Guest Additions was working fine until there were some updates in the CentOS system. Upon reboot, guest additions does not work. The disc shows on the desktop, and I choose auto run when it comes up, but all it does is have a window popup and disappear very clickly (within the blink of an eye), and thats it. No error messages.

When I choose "Install Guest Additions CD Image" from the VBox tool bar I get the following image:

[image: Error]

Where might I find a solution to this problem. I will be glad to find whatever info needed in the system, but not sure where to go. I have tried a couple of possible solutions from web searches, but so far I've had no success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this resolved it. manual install

http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-virtualbox-guest-additions-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/